# How to convert rawsql to query builder

Tags: php, laravel

how can I build a query builder from this rawsql.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM users
INNER JOIN votes ON user.id = votes.user_id
WHERE 
    voting_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'";
```

Comment: What is the  problem with this query ??

Comment: Please, try something first. Just asking to write code for you is a __bad idea__.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a table users, you 
can try something like this;

```
$query = DB::table('users')
->join('votes', 'users.id', '=', 'votes.user_id')
->whereBetween('votes.voting_date', [$from_date, $to_date])
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate ur help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$votes = DB::table('users')->join('votes','users.id','=','votes.user_id')
->whereBetween('voting_date',[$from_date,$to_date])->get();

//use db in your controller
```

Comment: Please give some explaination that will be usefull to futures reader

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use this

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM users
INNER JOIN votes ON user.id = votes.user_id
WHERE 
    voting_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'";
```

And execute the Query simply by

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw($sql));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this may be work for you:

```
$rsltUser = DB::table('users')
    ->join('votes','votes.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->whereBetween('voting_date',[$from_date,$to_date])->get();
```

Comment: Why you use Left join instead inner?

Comment: just for suggestion and please check my updated answer

Comment: Now looks ok left join will not work properly in this case.

Comment: @denny Ok good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the model `User` you can do this:

```
User::whereBetween('voting_date',[$from_date,$to_date])
    ->join('votes','users.id','=','votes.user_id')
    ->get();
```

It would be even better if you defined the relation with votes inside the model. Example:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```